# PercentRelativeLayout for api 21

Tags: android, xml, layout

i read on google developer about `PercentRelativeLayout` and this layout for minimum `api 23` in addition i searched in google if exist for solution to decrease this layout to `api 21` and i did not find anything, so my last resort is here maybe someone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is Percent Support Library - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#percent

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/package-summary.html

Comment: this is for api 23 like i said,i need for api 21

Comment: @moshekobi: No, it works back to API Level 7. Note, though, that it will be officially deprecated later this year.

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.3.0'` this is the libary you talk about?...if yes this is what i compiled, when you said deprecated it will be romved completely from android?